# Css styles just for second page when printing?

Tags: jquery, css, printing

Is there a way to apply styles just for the second page when printing with jquery (`window.print`) I have one div with two columns (`column-count:2`) that sometimes are overflowed to the second page. I need this div to fit the whole page, from side to side (1 column) if it overflows to the second page. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

use `@media print` query in your css

Please read https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Comment: how can I apply an style just for the second page?

Comment: you can apply styles to whichever css classes or id's you want within the media query and it will only apply to those classes or id's when the page is printed